# Creating a linked server in SQL Server 2008 to Progress Open Edge 10.1C via ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server, openedge, progress-db

I have a working ODBC connection to a Progress Open Edge 10.1C server (when I click "test connection" it passes)

How can I create a linked server in SQL Server that uses the ODBC connection?  I have tried but get this error message:

[image]

I'm using SQL Server 2008 on Win 2008 Server. I have no idea what the Progress server is running on. The ODBC DSN is created in the WOW64 ODBC manager (not the 32 bit ODBC manager).

This page is what comes up in Google when searching for that error message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx

> "To manage a data source that connects to a 32-bit driver under 64-bit
>   platform, use c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. To manage a data
>   source that connects to a 64-bit driver, use
>   c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe. In Administrative Tools on a 64-bit
>   Windows 8 operating system, there are icons for both the 32-bit and
>   64-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator dialog box. If you use the
>   64-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove a DSN that connects to a
>   32-bit driver, for example, Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb), you
>   will receive the following error message:
>
> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver
>   and Application
>
> To resolve this error, use the 32-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or
>   remove the DSN."

Comment: Typed too quickly - edited: SQL 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the correct answer was to dig around and find the 64 bit ODBC driver for OpenEdge.

Its not easy to find and I can't put a link here, I don't have one, the driver was sent to me by email.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 32 bit ODBC interface, run C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe (32 bit) and set your connections to the Progress DB there. (Is this Skyward?)